# Visual Studio Code - interconnected environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am investigating how feasible would it be to switch to Visual Studio Code with larger and more complex projects in **C++ with cmake** and have hit the wall regarding environmental variables.

Some projects I'm dealing with require a complex structure of interconnected environmental variables, currently this is solved by mostly manual build in bash prompt

```
$ source envSetupFile
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. && make -j $(nproc)
```

where the `envSetupFile` contains a lot of different variables, most cases related to toolchain and some specific settings. When those are just plain strings, everything works fine, however there are many cases of variables depending on another one, for example something like (in bash)

```
export PATH=/opt/custom/lib: $PATH
export ROOT=/some/path
export BIN=$ROOT/bin
export LIB=$ROOT/lib
```

## what I did

I installed the c/c++ extension package along with CMake and CMakeTools packages plus EditorConfig for VS Code
and added custom lines to the visual studio config in the workspace:
`/projectpath/.vscode/cmake-kits.json` where I set the environmental variables, but while I can set (and verify) directly defined work, any that requires value of another fails completely.

### example:

```
    "environmentVariables":{
        "POTATO": "aaa",
        "CARROT": "bbb",
        "CABAGE": "${POTATO}/${CARROT}"
    }
```

I'd expect that afterwards when running cmake which references ${CABAGE} would resolve it as `aaa/bbb`, but instead of it it takes them as string literals and produces `${POTATO}/${CARROT}` as ouptut

I must confess I'm a bit surprised by no trace of such use case in documentation or examples I've seen so far. Perhaps someone could lend a hand? (I'm running VisualStudio Code Version: 1.36.1 on ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Take a look at the [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) feature in VS Code. I also found the CMake extension to be too limiting so I wrote some scripts to clean, configure, build, install my project and I call them from VS Code's Run Task command. You can also set up problem matchers to display the errors in the VS Code UI.

Comment: Tried that, looked good but still problems (albeit new ones). It can't find basic commands such as ```env``` or ```make``` and cmake while executing, can't find any definition. Those exact same commands work fine from the terminal when done manually. I even tried making a shell script to fix this and call it - the scrip when called manually from the console works, but fails as part of a task